# How to change object's html?

Tags: javascript

I have an object captured by `infoTab.elements[1]`.

Here is the object  `Object { type="html",  html="or<hr>"}`.

How can I change object.html in the DOM?

Comment: `infoTab.elements[1].html = "something"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
infoTab.elements[1]; // Object { type="html",  html="or<hr>"} 

console.log(infoTab.elements[1].html); // or<hr>

infoTab.elements[1].html = "2<hr>";

console.log(infoTab.elements[1].html); // 2<hr>
```